# UWP Async MenuFlyout opening/opened

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app

I need to set my `MenuFlyout` in a programmatical way. However, I notice that with the async code added to my function, the `MenuFlyout` doesn't show its items unless I right click the item for the second time. How can I set my `MenuFlyout` in an async way?

```
private async void MenuFlyout_Opened(object sender, object e)
{
    var flyout = sender as MenuFlyout;
    Music music = flyout.Target.DataContext as Music;
    if (await Helper.FileNotExist(music.Path))
    {
        if (Removable)
        {
            flyout.Items.Clear();
            flyout.Items.Add(MenuFlyoutHelper.GetRemovableMenuFlyoutItem(music, this));
        }
        else
        {
            Helper.ShowAddMusicResultNotification(music.Name);
        }
        return;
    }
    if (Removable) MenuFlyoutHelper.SetRemovableMusicMenu(sender, this);
    else MenuFlyoutHelper.SetMusicMenu(sender, this);
    if (AllowReorder)
    {
        var item = new MenuFlyoutItem()
        {
            Text = Helper.Localize("Move To Top"),
            Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Upload)
        };
        item.Click += (s, args) =>
        {
            MediaHelper.MoveMusic(music.Index, 0);
        };
        flyout.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

One way is to avoid using async code in such functions and to check if file exists in the `Click` event of the items. But I have too many items. I think this is a bad idea.

This code works properly:

```
private void OpenMusicMenuFlyout(object sender, object e)
{
    if (Removable) MenuFlyoutHelper.SetRemovableMusicMenu(sender, this);
    else MenuFlyoutHelper.SetMusicMenu(sender, this);
    if (AllowReorder)
    {
        var flyout = sender as MenuFlyout;
        var item = new MenuFlyoutItem()
        {
            Text = Helper.Localize("Move To Top"),
            Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Upload)
        };
        item.Click += (s, args) =>
        {
            Music music = (s as MenuFlyoutItem).DataContext as Music;
            MediaHelper.MoveMusic(music.Index, 0);
        };
        flyout.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

---

Code with `Dispatcher.RunAsync`:

```
private async void OpenMusicMenuFlyout(object sender, object e)
{
    var flyout = sender as MenuFlyout;
    Music music = flyout.Target.DataContext as Music;
    if (await Helper.FileNotExist(music.Path))
    {
        if (Removable)
        {
            flyout.Items.Clear();
            flyout.Items.Add(MenuFlyoutHelper.GetRemovableMenuFlyoutItem(music, this));
        }
        else
        {
            Helper.ShowAddMusicResultNotification(music.Name);
        }
        return;
    }
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
    {

        if (Removable) MenuFlyoutHelper.SetRemovableMusicMenu(sender, this);
        else MenuFlyoutHelper.SetMusicMenu(sender, this);
        if (AllowReorder)
        {
            var item = new MenuFlyoutItem()
            {
                Text = Helper.Localize("Move To Top"),
                Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Upload)
            };
            item.Click += (s, args) =>
            {
                MediaHelper.MoveMusic(music.Index, 0);
            };
            flyout.Items.Add(item);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you try to add the `MenuFlyoutItem` in UI-thread by call Dispatcher.Run() method?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT This doesn't work.

Comment: Do you means `async void MenuFlyout_Opened` cause  flyout does not  display?

Comment: Actually, it displays the `MenuFlyoutItem` after first right click. But on the first appearance of the `MenuFlyout`, it is empty. @NicoZhu-MSFT

Comment: I found you have called async method in `MenuFlyout_Opened ` method,  could you try to call them with synchronization?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT How? Checking if file exists requires async method and I need that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213907/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-seaky-lone).

Answer (score 0):

Great question, for the testing, if we call async function in above `OpenMusicMenuFlyout` event handler,   `MenuFlyout` Add operation will be interrupted, and UI rendering will be canceled. For above scenario, the better way is make `Flyout` as `ContextFlyout` content then use `ListView` to replace `MenuFlyout`. For more please check the following.

```
<SwipeControl>
    <SwipeControl.ContextFlyout>
        <Flyout Opening="OpenMusicMenuFlyout">
            <ListView>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Flyout>
    </SwipeControl.ContextFlyout>
</SwipeControl>
```

**Code Behind**

```
private async void OpenMusicMenuFlyout(object sender, object e)
{
    var items = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "One", "Two", "Three" };
    var flyout = sender as Flyout;
    var menu =  flyout.Content as ItemsControl;
    await TestMetod();
    menu.ItemsSource = items;
}
```